# How can I write to my Samba share?

Tags: linux, permissions, samba

There are a million versions of this exact question out in google land but I've been unable to solve my problem (sorry). I have created a Samba share on Ubuntu 14.04 (actually xbmcbuntu) that I can connect to and read from, but not write to (from my Mac). I have followed a few different tutorials to get things set up so I probably have configured something incorrectly along the way.

The directory I am sharing (`/home/xbmc/raid/media`) is owned by the user xbmc and has permissions set to 775.

```
xbmc@xbmc:~$ ls -al raid
total 28
drwxr-xr-x  4 xbmc xbmc  4096 Sep  4 23:22 .
drwxr-xr-x 23 xbmc xbmc  4096 Sep  4 23:00 ..
drwx------  2 root root 16384 Sep  2 21:34 lost+found
drwxrwxr-x  9 xbmc xbmc  4096 Sep  4 22:58 media
```

If I change permissions to 777 I am able to write to the share but this feels like an inappropriate solution.

My `smb.conf` is as follows;

```
[global]
workgroup = WORKGROUP
server string = %h server (Samba, XBMC)
netbios name = XBMCbuntu
dns proxy = no
name resolve order = hosts wins bcast
#guest account = xbmc
load printers = no
show add printer wizard = no
log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
max log size = 1000
syslog = 0
panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
encrypt passwords = true
passdb backend = tdbsam
obey pam restrictions = yes
unix password sync = yes
passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
pam password change = yes
map to guest = bad user
security = user
username map = /etc/samba/smbusers

[System]
path = /home/xbmc/.xbmc
comment = XBMC System Share
writeable = yes
browseable = yes
guest ok = no

[Media]
path = /home/xbmc/raid/media
comment = xbmc media
writeable = yes
browseable = yes
guest ok = no
```

and `/etc/samba/smbusers` is as follows;

`xbmc = xbmc`

I've done a lot of fiddling with my smb.conf but haven't fixed anything. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add this to `[Media]` section:

```
public = no
hide unreadable = yes
printable = no
force create mode = 0664
force group = xbmc
write list = xbmc
directory mask = 0775
```

Do you authenticate to samba share as user xbmc under MacOS?

Comment: OK, that worked, althought I don't fully understand it. Am I opening myself to any security issues here (not that security is particularly important in my situation)?

Comment: It's cool, my statements assure that any file & directory written by samba will have xmbc as user & group and there will be proper permissions to let samba modify them in future.

Answer (score 0):

In your smb.conf file
Instead of using `writeable=yes` 
you must try using `write list=name_of_user`

Also you must set the selinux context to samba_share_t on the directory media as follows :

```
semanage -fcontext -a -t samba_share_t '/home/xbmc/raid/media(/.*)?'
```

And then you need to run this command :

```
restorcon -RvF /home/xbmc/raid/media
```

Everything else looks fine in your configuration file.